# Sql query - getting rid of hard-coded values

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
Select Name,
       case when charindex('I',a.S_Data) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as Illustrated,
       case when charindex('FP',a.S_Data) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as FrontPage,
       case when charindex('BP',a.S_Data) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as BackPage,
       case when charindex('ELP',a.S_Data) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as EDLP,
       case when charindex('PR',a.S_Data) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as SpecialPromo
From Table1
```

What I would like to do is to store those filter values in some sort of lookup table or a settings table.

I am struggling with how to draw the values from a lookup table to use with this query.

Comment: Not sure how much you'd gain, since I'm assuming you'd still want the hardcoded column names (`Illustrated`, `FrontPage`, etc.) associated with those values in your result set.

Comment: What about creating a view for this select?

Comment: Thats what I thought - ie, "is it worth it?"

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: What are the typical contents of the S_Data field? At the moment, each of the hard-coded values is displayed based on the presence of a particular (hard-coded) string within the field; does it only hold thosee values, or can it contain other data too?

Comment: why not use a view I don't think it's a bad thing to do the only thing which gives me doubts are the usages of the string function (charindex) and cases. Probably consider creating a small function returning varchar values depending on the result but that would be an overkill I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of at least two options...

```
CREATE TABLE constants (
  id               AS INT,
  Illustrated      AS VARCHAR(3),
  FrontPage        AS VARCHAR(3),
  BackPage         AS VARCHAR(3),
  EDLP             AS VARCHAR(3),
  SpecialPromo     AS VARCHAR(3)
)

INSERT INTO constants SELECT 1, 'I', 'FP', 'BP', 'ELP', 'PR'

SELECT
  Name,
  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(constants.Illustrated, data.S_Data) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   AS Illustrated,
  etc, etc
FROM
  data
INNER JOIN
  constants
    ON constants.id = 1
```

Or...

```
CREATE TABLE constants (
  constant_set_id  AS INT,
  constant_name    AS VARCHAR(16),
  value            AS AS VARCHAR(3)
)

INSERT INTO constants SELECT 1, 'Illustrated',  'I'
INSERT INTO constants SELECT 1, 'FrontPage',    'FP'
INSERT INTO constants SELECT 1, 'BackPage',     'BP'
INSERT INTO constants SELECT 1, 'EDLP',         'ELP'
INSERT INTO constants SELECT 1, 'SpecialPromo', 'PR'

SELECT
  Name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN constants.constant_name = 'Illustrated' AND CHARINDEX(constants.value, data.S_Data) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS Illustrated,
  etc, etc
FROM
  data
INNER JOIN
  constants
    ON constants.constant_set_id = 1
GROUP BY
  data.name
```

Both let you have multiple different sets of constants.  One is expandable without changing the schema, though the query still would need to change.

The main advantage of either approach is that you can re-use the constants else where, but store them once in a centralised location.  Which is only relevant if/when the values in the constants needs updating.  Re-use through indirection.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, your table apparently violates [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), since a single field can hold many values for a single record.

There are at least two ways this could be resolved:

(1) if the only values that can be stored in this field are the five specified in the query, it might make sense to replace the character field with five integer fields, each a flag for the specified condition - ie:

```
...
Illustrated int,
FrontPage int,
BackPage int,
EDLP int,
SpecialPromo int,
...
```

(2) If a variety of different conditions are to be stored, then I would suggest adding a lookup table for conditions, and a link table between the conditions and the original table - like so:

```
Conditions
----------
Condition_id
Description

Link_Table
----------
Table1_id
Condition_id
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it would appear that `Table1` is not first normal form (NFNF) because it violates the requirement that each tuple of has exactly one value for each attribute being of the type that is the declared type of that attribute i.e. the `S_Data` has multiple scalar types. You will suffer update anomalies e.g. deleting a setting presumably involves an `UPDATE` with text concatenation. Consider that SQL doesn't has operators that handle this kind of data (i.e. non-relational) very well.

Second, your output table is suboptimal becasue it returns the same type as multiple columns i.e. it looks more like a report.

Consider that the unit of work in SQL is the row:

```
CREATE TABLE Settings
(
 Setting VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO Settings VALUES ('Illustrated'), ('FrontPage'), ('BackPage'),
                            ('EDLP'), ('SpecialPromo');

CREATE TABLE Table1
(
 Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
 Setting VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
    REFERENCES Settings (Setting)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
 UNIQUE (Name, Setting)
);
```